# commonsware-cwac java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

every body ...

same of this link [cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

I have AppListener class :

```
public class AppListener implements WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener {

public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager amr, PendingIntent pi, Context ctx){
    amr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
}

public void sendWakefulWork(Context ctx){
    WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(ctx, AlarmServiceWakeful.class);
}

public long getMaxAge(){
    return (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES*2);
}

}
```

Then,I create an XML metadata file where identify the class that implements WakefulIntentService.AlarmListener ,so wakeful.xml:

```
<WakefulIntentService
listener="com.example.wakefulintentservicetest.AppListener"
/>
```

Next, registered my AlarmReceiver as a  in my manifest, set to respond to ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts, and with a com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful  element pointing to the XML resource from the previous step, akin to:

```
<receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful"
            android:resource="@xml/wakeful"/>
    </receiver>
```

too, uncommented below line in project.propertise:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

and added below code to the proguard-project.txt:

```
-keep class com.example.wakefulintentservicetest.** {
```

public protected private *;
}

but when I call below code in mainactivity ,oncreate method :

```
WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(new AppListener(), this, false);
```

gave me below error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/example/wakefulintentservicetest/AppListener
```

can every one help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your alarmReceiver's package defined wrong in your manifest.

`com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver`

It should be your package name:

`com.example.wakefulintentservicetest...`

Comment: I thought that but AlarmReciever is a class in jar File that add it to the project library..I think so.